# Mysql won't start because of the PID file

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, lamp

I've been trying to start Mysql but when I type

```
service mysql start
```

I get:

> Starting MySQL ... * The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).

Although I know I don't need to stop it because is not running, If I type:

```
service mysql stop
```

I get:

> Starting MySQL
>   ... * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).

I have already try to make the file in the proper directory but when I run the command to start Mysql I get the same error, and then somehow the file (mysqld.pid) disappears.

Since I installed compile Mysql from source code, I rerun all the commmands I typed when I first compiled it (I followed this guide: http://howtolamp.com/lamp/mysql/5.6/installing/)

Any help?

Comment: What is the business reason for compiling from the sources instead of using a precompiled package?

Comment: enable verbose logging and see mysql error log, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-log.html

Comment: It seems it can't open the mysql.plugin table.